# IIS set up effecting bots which is impacting on search results

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, seo, robots.txt, search-engine-bots

This is a tricky one to explain.  I believe the google bot is getting confused because of the way iis/sites are set up.  The actual issue is, when searching Google and the result is www.someSiteURL.com the description underneath is:

A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.

I think the reason the issue exists is fairly clear. Using the example above there is not page content at www.someSiteURL.com/default.asp  At this level there is a default.asp file with a whole bunch of redirects to take the user to the correct physical dir where the sites are.  The sites are all living under one root 'Site' in IIS like so:

```
siteOneDir
siteTwoDir  
siteThreeDir
default.asp (this is the page with the redirects)
```

How do you overcome this without chnaging the site setup/use of IPAddresses?

Here is the robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /default.asp
Allow: /siteOneDir/
Allow: /siteTwoDir/
Allow: /siteThreeDir/
Disallow: /
```

BTW Google webmaster tool says this is valid.  I know some clients may not recognize 'Allow' but Google and Bing do so I don't care about this.  I would rather disallow all then only allow sites instead of only using this to disallow specific sites.

If I use the Google webmaster tool Crawl > Fetch a Google and type in www.someSiteURL.com/default.asp it does have a status of 'Redirected' and its status is http/1.1 302 found

Comment: You should probably be doing 301 redirects, not 302. Not sure if that fixes the problem though.

Comment: @keith how do you specify a 302 instead?

Comment: see here http://webpaws.com/blog/6/classic-asp-header-redirect-302-object-moved/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order of the items in robot.txt matters. Try putting the disallow first, ie. change to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /default.asp
Allow: /siteOneDir/
Allow: /siteTwoDir/
Allow: /siteThreeDir/
```

Comment: it depends what client.  From reading the standards it seems best practice is to allow then disallow to cater for clients where only one instruction is read.  This is not the case for Google but is a possible scenario, apparently.

Comment: Okay, I might be mistaken. According to Google the most specific rule takes precedence.